# Troubles with positioning div inside the container

Tags: html, css

I have this:

[image]

I have the container:

```
.container {
max-width: 1140px;
margin: 0 auto;
position: relative;
}
```

And inner div inside the container:

```
.customers__inner {
position: absolute;
display: flex;
}
```

How do I stretch the block so that the entire page doesn't scroll horizontally?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to design it so that it doesn't scroll horizontally, add that option.

```css
overflow-x: hidden;
```

Comment: maybe insert .container object. this is css property